# Mysql where count

Tags: count, where-clause

I have this query. It selects all data from rena table and counts rows from gallery table, then collects records from rena table where Files>0. But the query doesn't work, I don't know what's wrong and how to fix it.

```
SELECT  fol.*,
    (SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM gallery fil 
      WHERE fil.ren_id = fol.id) AS "Files"
FROM rena fol where Files>0
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this.
nested query counts and then join with rena

```
SELECT fol.*,cnt FROM rena fol join 
(
select ren_id,count(*) cnt from gallery fil group by ren_id
    ) as aaa
on fol.id=aaa.ren_id
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how it works for MySQL but for Oracle i would do something like

```
SELECT fol.*, (SELECT count(*) FROM gallery fil 
                WHERE fil.ren_id = fol.id) AS "Files"
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM gallery fil 
                WHERE fil.ren_id = fol.id);
```

since you only need at least one file to match > 0 as soon as the db finds a row that matches  fil.ren_id = fol.id you should get the right result.